# Convert image to grayscale

Tags: c, image, swift, ios

To convert JPEG file, C function, bgraToGrayscale is called from Swift.

Is there a better way to

1.allocate memory and

2.access pointers

than the ways they have been done in code below?

And maybe things that have been completely missed, like freeing memory?

converter.swift

```
func BGRAToGrayscale(srcImg: CGImage) -> CGImage {
    let BytesPerPixel = 4

    guard let srcProv = srcImg.dataProvider else { fatalError("dataProvider is nil") }
    guard let srcProvData = srcProv.data else { fatalError("dataProvider.data is nil") }

    let srcPtr = CFDataGetBytePtr(srcProvData)
    let srcSize = srcImg.width * srcImg.height * BytesPerPixel

    var destPtr = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: srcSize)
    bgraToGrayscale(&destPtr, srcPtr, Int32(srcImg.width), Int32(srcImg.height))

    let destCgContext = CGContext(data: &destPtr,
                                  width: srcImg.width, height: srcImg.height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: srcImg.bitsPerComponent,
                                  bytesPerRow: srcImg.bytesPerRow,
                                  space: srcImg.colorSpace!,
                                  bitmapInfo: srcImg.bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    guard let destImg = destCgContext?.makeImage() else {
      fatalError("Destination Image is nil")
    }

    return destImg
}
```

converter.c (slow way of converting to grayscale, will write assembly code for this, just for the sake of learning :-) )

```
void bgraToGrayscale( unsigned char * __restrict dest, const unsigned char* src, int width, int height ) {
  int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;
  int numPixels = width * height;

  for( int idx=0; idx < numPixels; idx++ ) {

    float weight = ((float)src[0]) * 0.11 +
                  ((float)src[1]) * 0.59 +
                  ((float)src[2]) * 0.3;

    dest[0] = (int)weight;
    dest[1] = (int)weight;
    dest[2] = (int)weight;
    dest[3] = src[3];
    dest += BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
    src += BYTES_PER_PIXEL;
  }
}
```

Comment: You avoided doing any memory allocation in `bgraToGrayScale()`, so there's nothing to worry about. Unless you want this function to allocate memory for the converted image and return a pointer to that new image?

Comment: Before writing assembly code by hand, check what assembly code the compiler generates and then decide if you can do better. These days they are pretty good at vectorizing code like this. Of course it's fine for learning :)

Comment: (Beware that besides *coding* and the points you mentioned explicitly, there's floating point arithmetic. I'd drop an `assert(int(255f*.11+255f*.59+255f*.3) < 256)`. (hm, `==255`?))

Comment: Great idea to inspect generated assembly code. thanks @G.Sliepen

Comment: noted @greybeard

Comment: Compilers are better than humans at writing assembly code. See [this commit to the GCC project](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=fe596486d694e657413d0d4c5a04598674ff71b1). Someone deleted the hand-written assembly for the `logf` function, reinstating the plain-old C source code for it. Depending on architecture, latency was improved by up to 80% and throughput by up to 240%!

Comment: @CrisLuengo interesting, looks like logf function was written in assembly by hand in 1999 and it has not been updated properly to use advances in CPU architectures?

Comment: using CIFilter.colorMonochrome() is about 2x faster than code above, no surprise really.

Comment: I'd expect `unsigned  iweight = (src[0]*11u + src[1]*59u + src[2]*30u + 50u)/100u;` to be faster and less problematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Not following Swift naming conventions, should be bytesPerPixel
let BytesPerPixel = 4

// Better to make function throwable and throw specific error.
guard let srcProv = srcImg.dataProvider else { fatalError("dataProvider is nil") }
guard let srcProvData = srcProv.data else { fatalError("dataProvider.data is nil") }
```

For unwrap of `srcImg.colorSpace!` is not good solution, I would recommend to use `guard ... else` and throw an exception if value is nil.

Overall: why you are using abbreviations and shortcuts for every variable/constant name? It is much harder to read such code

Comment: trying to write relatively concise code, which why there are some abbreviations like src and dest, and prov. It is harder to read for the first time, i agree.